# SQL Server: how to troubleshoot login timeout expired error

Tags: sql-server-2012, python

I have a production SQL Server 2012 (SP1) running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.

A lot of time while connecting to this server from a remote host I to face connection timed out error. Developers also reported same error from their scripts as well.

Below is the error which I used to get from Management studio:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5)

However this is not so frequent and in next retry I use to connect to database.

From Python Scripts below is the error:

> 11/05/2015 10:21:01 AM [ERROR] ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
>   11/05/2015 10:21:11 AM [ERROR] global name 'traceback' is not defined

Above error is reported a lot of time by the scripts. In the SQL Server error log I didn't find any issue. Is there some issue with the SQL Server driver or with SQL Server?

Comment: Can be a network related problem. Is DNS fine? Did you try to use ip address in connection string? Do you use an alias?

Comment: Are there any network related errors in the errorlogs on the SQL Server?

Comment: Thia could be anything. I suggest you read here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is there some reason for using Named Pipes? NP work very well if you're connecting locally but its chatty nature does not work as well over the wire, especially if the network is even moderately busy. We have seen measurably slow performance and higher occurrences of timeouts with NP across the corporate network, less so in a small LAN or if machines are all connected to the same switch. You'll probably see network events in both the SQL Server error logs (as suggested by others above) and Windows event log.

Comment: what is the remote login timeout value for sql server

Answer (score 0):

*A lot of time while connecting to this server from a remote host I to face connection timed out error. Developers also reported same error from their scripts as well.*

Interestingly, it's not "all the time" which sounds like you can connect "some" of the time. Since this is intermittent it definitely sounds like a name resolution issue. Try registering and connecting to SQL Server with only the SQL Server IP address within SQL Server Studio.  For named instances you can type something like W.X.Y.Z\SQLInstanceName.